# Identify this East Asian-language movie, set in a radio station

Tags: identify-this-movie

I watched this movie sometime during 2003-2006 about a radio station that broadcasts a story, much like how Orson Wells broadcast War of the Worlds.

Anyway, it was an East Asian-language film, as I was reading the subtitles. I swear it was in Japanese, but it could be Chinese or Korean. I don't know. I know they were East Asian.

The story at some point had a damn blow up. To make practical sound effects, the people used Styrofoam cups and paper to create the sounds. They did this throughout the story for most if not all the sound effects.

Another point of interest was that someone in charge appointed a different person to narrate the story, as he had a better sounding voice. The narrator was male.

That's all I can remember about this movie. I posted  this same question years ago on Yahoo Answers, but nothing popped up.

**EDIT:**

Was almost certainly a Japanese movie. If I remember, there was a trucker or something that was totally captivated by this story over the radio.

I think the regular cast if you will, was not available for the show. As such, I think the story was heavily improvised, as the story changes quite drastically.

I think the effects were also locked up or something, as they used the flushing sound of a toilet as a damn bursting. The movie was made late 90's to early 00's, but not later than 2002, as the movie was on a channel that showed older movies, not recent DVD releases.

Comment: The only details I have are listed above. I don't know what was the point of having a story broadcasted over radio, as I missed the beginning of the film. The ending was pretty standard: well done, good show, see you tomorrow. Sorry, but that is all I have. Even then, I tried to find out when it would play next, which was during school time and never again after that, and I couldn't record it

Comment: adding more details in question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like the Japanese comedy [Welcome Back, Mr. McDonald](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welcome_Back,_Mr._McDonald) from 1997.

> A late-night live broadcast of a radio drama begins with none of the cast or crew being pleased with the project. When the lead actress Nokko Senbon (Keiko Toda) decides she won't play her role unless she's allowed to change her character's name, the whole cast eventually insists on changing various parts of the play to their liking. This begins a chain of events that completely changes every aspect of the story and requires the entire staff to participate in completing the drama, all while live on the air.

You can see them making the sound effects (and briefly recording the toilet flush) in the trailer: